# How to sort date with yyyy-mm-dd format. By using datatables [js]?

Tags: jquery, sorting, date, datatables

I need to sort date with yyyy-mm-dd format.

[From this document](http://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18). Here is my code.

```
$( function () {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment('YYYY-MM-DD');

    $('#tbTest').DataTable();
});
```

But I still got the wrong sort (See picture below)

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check the unshift function in the datatable plugin you see that moment has the strict parameter defined true.

```
    // Add type detection
    types.detect.unshift( function ( d ) {
    return moment( d, format, locale, true ).isValid() ?
        'moment-'+format :
        null;
    } );
```

From the [moment docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/):

> Moment's parser is very forgiving, and this can lead to undesired behavior. As of version 2.3.0, you may specify a boolean for the last argument to make Moment use strict parsing. Strict parsing requires that the format and input match exactly.

So instead of:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

which would require a date like 2015-04-01, you have to use:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('YYYY-M-D');
```